# Pandas fill empty column names with previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Newbie here.
Try to clean up the following column name presented

`1992 | Unnamed: 2 |  Unnamed: 3 | 1993 |  Unnamed: 4|  Unnamed: 5| 1994 | ... | 2015 |  Unnamed: 22 |  Unnamed: 23|`

Next column is

`Male | Female | Population | Male | Female | Population ....`

Then, the row and beyond are to do with each country's populations

I try the following to clean up all the unnamed column names

```
df.columns = map(lambda x: np.nan if (re.search(r'\bUnnamed:\s\d{1,2}\b', x)) else x, df.columns)
```

Then I wanted to naively do a fillna function with pad method...

```
df_column_names = df_column_names.fillna(method='pad')
```

obviously that didn't work

Should I just extract the column name, manipulate it as dataframe and use the `fillna(method='pad')` and then just magically merge it back with the working dataframe?

Seems to be very clunky way to do it.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what you want to achieve. Could you please provide sample of the DataFrame you have and sample of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I think i have an answer. Thanks @Tom83B for the question.

My solution is to convert df.columns above as pd.Series, then run fillna(method='pad) function. As a result,  all NaN will be populated with the precedent year value.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have an answer. My solution is to convert df.columns above as pd.Series, then run fillna(method='pad) function. As a result, all NaN will be populated with the precedent year value